sssd, autofs - can see autofs maps (samba4, NIS scheme)
I have nfs4 server with one share
[root@nfssrv.test.my] # cat /etc/exports
/srv/public *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p)

On Samba i create maps for sssd_autofs - see below with ldbsearch (or ldapsearch)
[root@dc]# ldbsearch -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb -b OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my 

# record 1
dn: CN=/-,CN=auto.master,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
cn: /-
distinguishedName: CN=/-,CN=auto.master,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
instanceType: 4
name: /-
nisMapEntry: auto.nfs
nisMapName: auto.master
objectCategory: CN=NisObject,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=test,DC=my
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisObject
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE

# record 2
dn: CN=/mnt/nfs,CN=auto.nfs,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
cn: /mnt/nfs
distinguishedName: CN=/mnt/nfs,CN=auto.nfs,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
instanceType: 4
name: /mnt/nfs
nisMapEntry: -fstype=nfs4,rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p nfssrv.test.my:/srv/public
nisMapName: auto.nfs
objectCategory: CN=NisObject,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=test,DC=my
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisObject
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE

# record 3
dn: CN=auto.nfs,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
cn: auto.nfs
distinguishedName: CN=auto.nfs,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
instanceType: 4
name: auto.nfs
nisMapName: auto.nfs
objectCategory: CN=NisMap,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=test,DC=my
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisMap
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE

# record 4
dn: CN=auto.master,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
cn: auto.master
distinguishedName: CN=auto.master,OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
instanceType: 4
name: auto.master
nisMapName: auto.master
objectCategory: CN=NisMap,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=test,DC=my
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisMap
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE


# record 5
dn: OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
distinguishedName: OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
instanceType: 4
name: automount
objectCategory: CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=test,DC=my
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: automount

On windows (rsat) side, it looks like this

At next, configure client side sssd
[root@host-15 ~]# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss,pam,ssh,autofs
user = _sssd
domains = TEST.MY

[autofs]
debug_level = 9
[nss]
[sudo]
[pam]

[domain/TEST.MY]    
autofs_provider = ad
ldap_autofs_search_base = OU=automount,DC=test,DC=my
ldap_autofs_map_object_class = nisMap
ldap_autofs_map_name = nisMapName
ldap_autofs_entry_object_class = nisObject
ldap_autofs_entry_key = cn
ldap_autofs_entry_value = nisMapEntry

# the following lines are not related to this problem

sudo_provider = ad
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
default_shell = /bin/bash
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
debug_level = 0
ad_gpo_ignore_unreadable = true
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
ad_update_samba_machine_account_password = true
cache_credentials = false
debug_level = 0x3ff0
#entry_cache_sudo_timeout = 30
ad_sudo_search_base = ou=sudoers,dc=test,dc=my
ad_sudo_full_refresh_interval = 10
ldap_user_extra_attrs = altSecurityIdentities:altSecurityIdentities
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
ldap_use_tokengroups = True
dyndns_update = true

remove all sssd caches, restart services
rm -fr /var/lib/sss/mc/* &&  rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/* && systemctl restart sssd autofs

/var/log/sssd/sssd_autofs.log
(2024-10-15 11:28:18): [autofs] [sss_responder_ctx_destructor] (0x0400): Responder is being shut down
(2024-10-15 11:28:18): [autofs] [orderly_shutdown] (0x3f7c0): SIGTERM: killing children
(2024-10-15 11:28:18): [autofs] [orderly_shutdown] (0x3f7c0): Shutting down (status = 0)
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [server_setup] (0x3f7c0): Starting with debug level = 0x2f7f0
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [server_setup] (0x0400): CONFDB: /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [confdb_init_domain_provider_and_enum] (0x0400): No enumeration for [TEST.my]!
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [confdb_init_domain_provider_and_enum] (0x0400): Please note that when enumeration is disabled `getent passwd` does not return all users by design. See sssd.conf man page for more detailed information
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [confdb_init_domain_pwd_expire] (0x1000): pwd_expiration_warning is -1
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/sh in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/bash in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/ash in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/bsh in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/csh in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/tcsh in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/ksh in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/zsh in /etc/shells
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_names_init_from_args] (0x0100): Using re [^(((?P<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?P<name>.+))|((?P<name>.+)@(?P<domain>[^@]+))|((?P<name>[^@\\]+)))$].
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_fqnames_init] (0x0100): Using fq format [%1$s@%2$s].
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dbus_connect_address] (0x0400): Connected to unix:path=/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_TEST.my bus as sssd.autofs
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable on path /
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable on path /*
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties on path /
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties on path /*
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_watch_add] (0x2000): Created a disabled -/W watch on 13
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_watch_toggle] (0x4000): Toggle to enabled R/- watch on 13
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_listen] (0x0400): Registering signal listener org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged on path /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_listen] (0x0400): Registering signal listener org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired on path /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface sssd.Responder.Domain on path /sssd
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface sssd.Responder.NegativeCache on path /sssd
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): DB File for TEST.MY: /var/lib/sss/db/cache_TEST.my.ldb
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sysdb_domain_init_internal] (0x0200): Timestamp file for TEST.my: /var/lib/sss/db/timestamps_TEST.my.ldb
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sysdb_ldb_connect] (0x4000): No ldb module path set in env
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [ldb] (0x0400): asq: Unable to register control with rootdse!
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sysdb_ldb_connect] (0x4000): No ldb module path set in env
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_names_init_from_args] (0x0100): Using re [^(((?P<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?P<name>.+))|((?P<name>.+)@(?P<domain>[^@]+))|((?P<name>[^@\\]+)))$].
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_fqnames_init] (0x0100): Using fq format [%1$s@%2$s].
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_process_init] (0x0400): Responder initialization complete (explicitly configured)
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dbus_connect_address] (0x0400): Connected to unix:path=/var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor bus as sssd.autofs
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable on path /
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable on path /*
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties on path /
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties on path /*
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_watch_add] (0x2000): Created a disabled -/W watch on 19
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_watch_toggle] (0x4000): Toggle to enabled R/- watch on 19
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_listen] (0x0400): Registering signal listener org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged on path /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_listen] (0x0400): Registering signal listener org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired on path /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_router_add_path] (0x0400): Registering interface sssd.service on path /sssd
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [autofs_process_init] (0x0400): autofs Initialization complete
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_signal_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus signal org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired on /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_signal_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus signal org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired on /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_signal_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus signal org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired on /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_name_acquired] (0x0400): D-Bus name acquired: :1.5
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired: Success
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_signal_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus signal org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired on /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_name_acquired] (0x0400): D-Bus name acquired: :1.6
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired: Success
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_name_acquired] (0x0400): D-Bus name acquired: sssd.autofs
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired: Success
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_name_acquired] (0x0400): D-Bus name acquired: sssd.autofs
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): org.freedesktop.DBus.NameAcquired: Success
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_signal_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus signal org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged on /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_dp_init_done] (0x0400): Client is registered with DP
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_name_owner_changed] (0x4000): Name of owner sssd.ssh has changed from [] to [sssd.ssh]
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged: Success
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sss_monitor_service_init_done] (0x0100): Got id ack and version (1) from Monitor
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_signal_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus signal org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged on /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_name_owner_changed] (0x4000): Name of owner :1.7 has changed from [] to [:1.7]
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged: Success
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_signal_handler] (0x2000): Received D-Bus signal org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged on /org/freedesktop/DBus
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_name_owner_changed] (0x4000): Name of owner sssd.ssh has changed from [] to [sssd.ssh]
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [autofs] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged: Success
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): Domain TEST.MY is Active
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [cache_req_domain_new_list_from_domain_resolution_order] (0x0400): Domain resolution order list: not set
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [sysdb_get_certmap] (0x0400): No certificate maps found.
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [sss_ncache_set_str] (0x0400): Adding [NCE/USER/TEST.MY/root@test.my] to negative cache permanently
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [sss_ncache_set_str] (0x0400): Adding [NCE/GROUP/TEST.MY/root@test.my] to negative cache permanently
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [sss_ncache_set_str] (0x0400): Adding [NCE/UID/0] to negative cache permanently
(2024-10-15 11:28:32): [autofs] [sss_ncache_set_str] (0x0400): Adding [NCE/GID/0] to negative cache permanently

tail -2000  /var/log/sssd/sssd_TEST.MY.log  | grep autofs
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [dp_target_init] (0x0400): Initializing target [autofs] with module [ad]
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [dp_target_run_constructor] (0x0400): Executing target [autofs] constructor
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sssm_ad_autofs_init] (0x2000): Initializing AD autofs handler
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [ad_autofs_init] (0x2000): Initializing autofs AD back end
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_autofs_init] (0x2000): Initializing autofs LDAP back end
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_object_class has value nisMap
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_name has value nisMapName
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_object_class has value nisObject
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_key has value cn
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_value has value nisMapEntry
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_object_class has value nisMap
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_name has value nisMapName
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_object_class has value nisObject
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_key has value cn
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_value has value nisMapEntry
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_server_bus_request_name] (0x0400): Requesting name: sssd.autofs
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.autofs]
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.autofs]
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_add] (0x2000): Inserting identity of sender [sssd.autofs]: 487
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [dp_client_register] (0x0100): Added Frontend client [autofs]
(2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.autofs]
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [dp_target_init] (0x0400): Initializing target [autofs] with module [ad]
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [dp_target_run_constructor] (0x0400): Executing target [autofs] constructor
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sssm_ad_autofs_init] (0x2000): Initializing AD autofs handler
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [ad_autofs_init] (0x2000): Initializing autofs AD back end
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_autofs_init] (0x2000): Initializing autofs LDAP back end
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_object_class has value nisMap
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_name has value nisMapName
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_object_class has value nisObject
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_key has value cn
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_value has value nisMapEntry
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_object_class has value nisMap
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_map_name has value nisMapName
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_object_class has value nisObject
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_key has value cn
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sdap_get_map] (0x0400): Option ldap_autofs_entry_value has value nisMapEntry
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_server_bus_request_name] (0x0400): Requesting name: sssd.autofs
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_name_owner_changed] (0x4000): Name of owner sssd.autofs has changed from [] to [sssd.autofs]
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.autofs]
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.autofs]
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_add] (0x2000): Inserting identity of sender [sssd.autofs]: 487
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [dp_client_register] (0x0100): Added Frontend client [autofs]
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_name_owner_changed] (0x4000): Name of owner sssd.autofs has changed from [] to [sssd.autofs]
   *  (2024-10-15 11:28:29): [be[TEST.MY]] [sbus_senders_lookup] (0x2000): Looking for identity of sender [sssd.autofs]

but automount -m does not see maps
[root@host-15 ~]# grep automount /etc/nsswitch.conf
automount:  files sss
[root@host-15 ~]# /usr/sbin/automount -m | grep sss
...nothing...

ssd-2.9.4
autofs-sss
samba-4.19.7
autofs-5.1.8

remove 'files' from 'automount' section in /etc/nsswitch.conf - all working file..
before
automount: files sss
after
automount: sss
o_O ? how use both?
